# How to setup in EF Core, with Fluent API the default value for is required globally?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I created my first initial migration with some tables and columns, but I saw a thing, all my fields are not null and to every field which I want nullable (almost all) I need to specify the `IsRequired(false)`

[image]

There is a way to setup that all the fields to be nullable and only call the isRequired() (true) for those which I want to be required?

**I don't want to use data annotations, or something else, only Fluent Api,** so only if it exists a global setting for that in Fluent Api otherwise I will put to every field IsRequired. I want to decouple the models from FluentApi Config file because in the future if I want to use another ORM I only need to change FluentApi Config files.

Comment: Please put in your code "as text" . not a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In your Entity you can set the properties to be nullable

```cs
Public class Booking 
{
        public Guid? MyProperty{ get; set; }

        public int? MyProperty{ get; set; }

        public decimal? MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Or use `JetBrains.Annotations`

```cs
using JetBrains.Annotations;

Public class Booking 
{
        [CanBeNull]
        public Guid MyProperty{ get; set; }

        [CanBeNull]
        public int MyProperty{ get; set; }

        [CanBeNull]
        public decimal MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you setup your class you can work with nullable value types
exemple :

```
public class a {

int? a { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "No".

You can add a class and static method to provide a single-source-of-truth constants.

```
public static class MyDefaultDictionary() {

   /* the below is false because ___________________ */
   public const bool IsRequiredDefault = false;

}
```

and

```
 .IsRequired(MyDefaultDictionary.IsRequiredDefault);
```